# Warning: React version not specified in 'eslint-plugin-react settings' while running eslint on top of React 18.2.0

Tags: reactjs, eslint

### Issue

Git bash shows `Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .` while running eslint.

### How to produce

```
create-react-app my-app
cd app
npm install eslint --save-dev
npx eslint --init
npx eslint .
```

### package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1"
  }
}
```

I tried to find solutions but failed.
I kindly ask for your help.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Add this to your config in .eslintrc:

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

See the config here: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/README.md#configuration

Comment: This should be the answer. Not sure why it's not marked checked.

Comment: Yeah, this actually works. I've accepted this answer, @BonAndreOpina

Comment: The settings property should be added to the eslintrc.json file along with the other options like rules and plugins.

Comment: @alex-jesper thanks, I wish the docs were more clear about that.

Answer (score 10):

Inside your `folder root` edit `.eslintrc.js` file and put `"version": "detect"`. Like

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    react: {
     version: "detect",
    },
  },
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the [new eslint.config.js](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new), I did the below (with typescript). I tried to follow the [official README](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/README.md#configuration-new-eslintconfigjs) but it wasn't too helpful.

```
import react from "eslint-plugin-react";
import typescriptEslint from "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin";
import typescriptParser from "@typescript-eslint/parser";
import globals from "globals";
import reactRecommended from "eslint-plugin-react/configs/recommended.js";

export default [
  {
    ignores: ["dist/**/*"],
  },
  {
    files: ["**/*.{js,jsx,mjs,cjs,ts,tsx}"],
    ignores: ["dist/**/*"],
    ...reactRecommended,
    settings: {
      version: "detect",
    },
    languageOptions: {
      ...reactRecommended.languageOptions,
      ecmaVersion: "latest",
      sourceType: "module",
      parser: typescriptParser,
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
          jsx: true,
        },
      },
      globals: {
        ...globals.serviceworker,
        ...globals.browser,
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      "@typescript-eslint": typescriptEslint,
      react,
    },
    rules: {
      //rules here
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Just fyi, should be: `settings: { react: { version: "detect" } }` (but thanks for posting this because it helped!)

Answer (score -8):

The problem is in the `eslint-plugin-react` v.7.30.1.
Downgrade it to v.7.30.0 and it will work

```
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0"
```